# GeoDjango GeoQuerySet.distance() results in 'ST_Distance output only available on GeometryFields' when specifying a reverse relationship in field_name

Tags: python, django, django-models, postgis, geodjango

From the docs and other questions, sorting a GeoQuerySet by distance should be straightforward, but I'm having trouble getting it work. Here is an example to demonstrate the situation of the problem:

Lets say I got two models in two different apps. One model in appA and another in appB as defined below:

```
# appA/models.py
class Store(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField()


# appB/models.py
from appA.models import Store

class StoreLocation(models.Model):
    store = models.ForiegnKey(Store)
    location = models.PointField()
```

Now, I want to get all the `Stores` that are within two miles of a user's location (`user_location`) like so:

```
stores = Store.objects.filter(storelocation__location__dwithin(user_location, D(mi=2))
```

So far so good. Everything up to here works. The problem starts when I want to now sort the `Stores` by their distance to `user_location`:

```
stores = Store.objects.filter(storelocation__location__dwithin(user_location, D(mi=2))\
         .distance(user_loc, field_name='storelocation__location')\
         .order_by('distance')
```

This results into `TypeError: ST_Distance output only available on GeometryFields`.

The `location` field of the `StoreLocation` model is a `PointField` which is a `GeometryField`. So the issue is with the reverse relationship lookup done by `field_name='storelocation__location'`.

There is a Django support ticket (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22352) requesting support for reverse relationship lookups in `field_name` for OneToOne relationships, but my models have a OneToMany relationship through a ForeignKey so I'm not sure if the support ticket applies to this problem.

Judging from the Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#geoqueryset-methods) it doesn't seem like I'm misusing anything here.

Are reverse relationship lookups allowed with the `field_name` argument of GeoQuerySet methods? Or am I just doing something wrong?

The solution provided in this question ([GeoDjango distance query for a ForeignKey Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068457/geodjango-distance-query-for-a-foreignkey-relationship)) didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are getting bit by the same issue mentioned in [Django support ticket 22352](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22352), since related fields (whether one-to-one or one-to-many) share much of the same code.

You can still efficiently get nearby stores ordered by distance:

```
locations = StoreLocation.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(user_location, D(mi=2)))
locations = locations.distance(user_location).order_by('distance')
stores = [sl.store for sl in locations.select_related('store')]
```

However, this loses the benefits of having `stores` be a queryset (which could be further filtered, sliced, etc).

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the answer. Thank you, now I know it wasn't just something I was doing wrong. Hopefully the proposed patch for the ticket will get into a release. Also, for the sake of completeness, if someone wants to to get (inefficiently) QuerySet out this list they can refer to this trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4790371/394988