# Custom SQL for Geodjango on ForignKey

Tags: django, django-models, gis, postgis, geodjango

I have a following model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    location = models.PointField(blank=True, null=True, srid=CONSTANTS.SRID)

    objects = models.GeoManager()

class Item(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)

    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Now I need to sort the Items by distance to some point:

```
p = Point(12.5807203, 50.1250706)
Item.objects.all().distance(p, field='owner__location')
```

But that throws me an error:

```
TypeError: ST_Distance output only available on GeometryFields.
```

From [GeoDjango GeoQuerySet.distance() results in 'ST_Distance output only available on GeometryFields' when specifying a reverse relationship in field_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047964/geodjango-geoqueryset-distance-results-in-st-distance-output-only-available-o) I can see there is already ticket for this.

Now I don't like the solution proposed in that question since that way I would not get the distance and I would lose the distances.

So I was thinking that I could achieve this by making a custom sql query. I know that this:

```
UserProfile.objects.distance(p)
```

will produce something like this:

```
SELECT (ST_distance_sphere("core_userprofile"."location",ST_GeomFromEWKB('\x0101000020e6100000223fd12b5429294076583c5002104940'::bytea))) AS "distance", "core_userprofile"."id", "core_userprofile"."user_id", "core_userprofile"."verified", "core_userprofile"."avatar_custom", "core_userprofile"."city", "core_userprofile"."location", "core_userprofile"."bio" FROM "core_userprofile"
```

So my question is: is there some easy way how to manually construct such query that would sort items by distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the geometry you're measuring distance to is on `UserProfile`, it makes sense to query for `UserProfile` objects and then handle each `Item` object they own. (The distance is the same for all items owned by a profile.)

For example:

```
all_profiles = UserProfile.objects.all()
for profile in all_profiles.distance(p).order_by('distance'):
   for item in profile.item_set.all():
       process(item, profile.distance)
```

You may be able to make this more efficient with [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
all_profiles = UserProfile.objects.all()
all_profiles = all_profiles.prefetch_related('item_set')  # we'll need these
for profile in all_profiles.distance(p).order_by('distance'):
   for item in profile.item_set.all():  # items already prefetched
       process(item, profile.distance)
```

If it's important for some reason to query directly for `Item` objects, try using [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra):

```
items = Item.objects.all()
items = items.select_related('owner')
distance_select = "st_distance_sphere(core_userprofile.location, ST_GeomFromEWKT('%s'))" % p.wkt
items = items.extra({'distance': distance_select})
items = items.order_by('distance')
```

[Raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) are another option, which let you get model objects from a raw SQL query:

```
items = Item.objects.raw("SELECT core_item.* FROM core_item JOIN core_userprofile ...")
```